# Laravel 4 with Data Mapper?

Tags: php, laravel, datamapper, phpactiverecord

Does anyone know if Laravel has some sort of library/plugin or tweak to use Data Mapper or to make Active Record behave like Data Mapper?.

I'm not a Laravel user,so perhaps Eloquent is using a mix of Active Record and Data Mapper and I'm not aware of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, we can implement the Data Mapper pattern into Laravel using Doctrine;

Packagist:   https://packagist.org/packages/atrauzzi/laravel-doctrine

Laravel Doc: http://bundles.laravel.com/bundle/doctrine